# How to change position of newsletter box in Magento sidebar?

Tags: php, magento

I have a newsletter box in my Magento sidebar that I need to change the position of.

It appears beneath the `app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/callouts/right_col.php` template.

I've been trying to get my head around the XML files for layout. I couldn't find any mention of newsletter in `page.xml` or `catalog.xml`. There is a `newsletter.xml`, but I couldn't get my head around it.

How do I move it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in **newsletter.xml**

```
<default>    
<reference name="left">
     <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" before="-" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

you have this options:

- before="-"
- after="-"
- before="name-other-module" **or** after="name-other-module"

Comment: have more information here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

Answer (score 2):

You can open up `newsletter.xml` and find this

```
<default>

    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="right.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```

Then add an attribute to `block` titled `before` and set its value to "-", as in...

```
<default>

    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="right.newsletter" before="-" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```